# getting the output of gyroscope sensor Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gyroscope

I am trying to get the gyroscope sensor result in Android studio. Then display an arrow UI indicting the direction. I wrote this code but there are two problem.

1. When I start playing with the device is not showing the correct arrow
2. How to refresh the value when user move the phone.

```
public class NavigationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private Sensor gyroscope;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private ImageView go, right, left, back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        go = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_go);
        right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_right);
        left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_left);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_back);

        go.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gyroscope = (Sensor)mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Register for sensor update
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);}   
}
```

This is the OnSensorChanged: http://postimg.org/image/4my837rr9/ (On the same code above)
This is the UI:
http://s24.postimg.org/6gfyy2qrp/Stack.png

**P.S

1.The default *Screen Orientation is "landscape"* 

2.The Information I build my (azimuth, pitch, and roll) on is according to the following:**


values[0]: Azimuth, rotation around the Z axis (0<=azimuth<360). 0 = North, 90 = East, 180 = South, 270 = West

values[1]: Pitch, rotation around X axis (-180<=pitch<=180), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the y-axis.

values[2]: Roll, rotation around Y axis (-90<=roll<=90), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the x-axis.

Comment: Do not post screen shots of your code, post the code it in your question.

Comment: I had problem writing the code in the editor.